# Postgres replication globally

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Please advise which Postgres version is better for setting up a replication between a master which resides in one continent and one of its standby server is located in a different continent, and network latency is high.

Thanks.

Comment: For any new installation you should always consider the current version (9.6 at the time of this writing). For a low latency replication it's log shipping is probably your best choice: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html

Comment: We are doing streaming replications as its giving us better results, but a lag is always there, which is painful!

Comment: So your real question is: "*How do we make the replication that we have faster?*" I guess the only answer is to improve the network speed and latency.

Comment: have you tried synchronous replication as mentioned by Arkhena?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but IT isn't magic...
If your network has high latency how can you expect data change to be spread without latency ?

But if you don't care about your writing rate on the master, you can slow it down with synchronous replication and you won't have any latency between your master and your standby. Of course you will now face writing lag on your master!

I'm afraid postgreSQL isn't suitable for your need in that case... 
Here, you're facing the CAP theorem issue. Maybe, you could try another approach to favor consistency and partition tolerance as MongoDB, BigTable or Redis ?